# How to carry over selected items to new page with JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having users click on a dropdown next to an image for two options say Shirt or Mug. They are then directed to the purchase page and need to have the Shirt/Mug selected AND the image selected.

I have the following for HTML for the landing page:

```
      <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 wk-left">
      <img class="wk-img"/>
      <%= image_tag('image.jpg', class: 'wk-img') %>
      <p class="image-header wk-img-head">Header</p>
      <p class="image-text">Sub Header</p>
      <p class="image-text">
        Some text
      </p>
      <br/>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn merch dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Get a Collectible
            <span class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:16px;"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="/url/image.jpg&type=shirt">T-Shirt</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/url/image.jpg&type=mug">Mug</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

For the product page I have JS to parse through the parameters:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
if (!url) url = window.location.href;
name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));}

var type = getParameterByName('type');
var image = getParameterByName('image');
```

I have the following jQuery for everything:

```
$(function(){
  $('div [button_type="'+ type +  '"]').addClass('btn wk-prd-btn pink');
  $('div [image-var="'+ image + '"]').removeClass('img-container1 image-container image-size img-pink').addClass('img-container1 image-size wk-after image-container');
});
```

So the button works on page re-load. They are marked with whatever the user clicks. The images, not so much. The above is the most recent as I've been playing with stripping out the class before adding back in. I think the issue is applying the container when page is loaded. Struggling to get it to be present though. I've included the CSS as well.

CSS:

```
.image-container:hover .wk-after, .image-container.active .wk-after{
display: block;
background: rgba(231, 68, 129, 0.75);
}

.wk-after{
 display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;}

.image-container.active .wk-after {
display: block;
background: rgba(231, 68, 129, 0.75);}

.image-container .wk-after {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
font-size: 16px;
display: none;
color: #FFF;}
```

Am I missing something that should apply the styling?

Comment: You would either need to make use of `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` or `cookies` in order to store the data between pages, or make use of AJAX or a form submission to `POST` it to a database. Although considering you're passing through the product in the URL on click,
 you could always just extract the product from the URL on the second page (though I wouldn't recommend that for a store system).

Comment: I'm actually extracting parameters on the second page, parsing and then applying classes. Neglected to include the JS code for extracting the parameters. I added that in.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. Just required the following:

```
$(function(){
 $('div [image-var="'+ image + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```